# Do tenses agree in: ""I don't understand why the service was so slow.."

Tags: tense, subordinate-clauses, tense-agreement

My friend was like

> "I don't understand why the service was so slow.."

Why I can find no tense consistency here? Is it grammatically correct ? or it is just acceptable in spoken english rather than writing?

Comment: What is exactly inconsistent here? Is it that in your guessing the present tense in the main clause ("I **don't** understand") jars with the past tense in the subordinate clause ("the service **was** so slow")?

Comment: I don't understand why there was a powercut yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

> I **don't understand** why the service **was** so slow...

*understanding* is not a momentary occurrence. You didn't understand then, and you still don't understand now.

So it relates to both the past and present situation.

It is grammatical as written.

Answer (score 0):

Let us take an example from your question:

Suppose, I already **knew** the answer to your question. So, when we meet **now**, I would say:

> I **don't** understand why you **were** confused about tense consistency.

I think it is a common expression to describe any past event/activity that you don't understand at present. Check:

> I **don't** understand *(at present)* why there **was** *(a past event)* a powercut yesterday.

It is grammatical and acceptable.